# Add an element into an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array and an object collection(not an object..). 
One looks like this:

```
array = new Array[1,2,3,4,5]
```

The other looks like this:

```
{number:1, letter:a}
{number:2, letter:b}
{number:3, letter:c}
{number:5, letter:e}
```

How can I push

```
{number:4, letter:d}
```

into the object?

```
for (var i=0, arrLen=array.length; i<arrLen; ++i){
 if( obj.number != array[i]{
    obj.push(create an object) // I don't know how to create such an object
    }
}
```

I have tried other ways, but I don't think [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) works.

```
for ( var k = 0, kLen = dateList.length; k < kLen; ++k){
        if(obj.date.indexOf(dateList[k]) === -1){
            obj.push() // I don't know how to push {number:4, letter:d}  in
        }
    }
```

======================

There were a lot of confusions...
I want the final output to be in an object collection. But first I need to find the "missing object" according to the `array`

Comment: You cannot `push` data into object.

Comment: Your second definition describes 4 objects, not just one. Is `obj` an array of objects, or is your notation incorrect?

Comment: @hsz  can I reconstruct an object 'var empty =[];empty.push(obj);empty.push(new stuff)' ?

Comment: @walterudoing `var empty = []` creates an empty `Array`, not an object. `empty.push(obj)` then pushes an object into that array.

Comment: @Phylogenesis =.=  What about `var empty = new Object(); empty.number=4;empty.letter=d;`?

Comment: That creates a new `Object` with 2 properties: `number` and `letter`. None of this has helped clarify what you're *actually* trying to do. An answer below has attempted to guess your intentions.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Firstly, I want to find the "missing object" according to the `array`; then I need to create an object according to the `array` and add it to the object collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript-Syntax doesn't require you to instantiate Objects, you can simply define them.

So if you have above arrays

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var object_array = [
   {number:1, letter:a}
   {number:2, letter:b}
   {number:3, letter:c}
   {number:5, letter:e}
  ];
```

you have to iterate over the Object Array to find the "missing" Object like this.
Be careful to check for undefined, because if there is a "missing" Object you may encounter an error.

```
for(var i=0, j= array.length;i<j;i++){
   if(object_array[i] === undefined || object_array[i].number !== i){
       object_array.splice(i,0, {number: i, letter: d});
   } 
}
```

What I did not anticipate is how you would get the correct letter, but though I think this is some kind of Pseudocode, you may work out the correct letter for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather in the comments you are looking to push an object into an **array** and not into another *object*.

Doing this is actually very simple. You simply take your original array and push your object to it. I.E.

```
var array = []; // This contains your current objects

array.push({number:4, letter:'d'}); // Push your new object into the array
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for the confusion. Firstly, I want to find the "missing object" according to the `array`; then I need to create an object according to the `array` and add it to the object collection.